# How to do bonding in ubuntu 12.04 in vmware workstation?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, vmware, network-bonding

I followed process for bonding which is given on this site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

but output is

```
$ cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)
Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: down
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
```

and

```
$ ifconfig
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 86:df:fa:d9:19:30  
          inet addr:172.16.71.11  Bcast:172.16.71.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:89822 (89.8 KB)  TX bytes:89822 (89.8 KB)
```

And the status of other two device `eth0` and `eth1` shows that 'device not managed', So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before applying bonding, need to close network. In my case, following command is used:

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

Instead of:

```
sudo stop networking
```

After editing in `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces` file, need to restart network using:

```
sudo start network-manager
```

Or reboot Ubuntu.

Its works fine, but still I don't know why it show:

```
device not managed
```

Comment: Device not managed means that the Ubuntu Network Manager is not managing the device, occurs when you configure interfaces via /etc/network/interfaces...